# 404 Not Found on previously working website

Tags: apache, webserver, apache2

I previously had a website that I was hosting personally on a ubuntu server 16.04 LTS, sort of just a project to show that I knew what I was doing. (Turns out I don't have a clue!)

The site was/is structured such that I have a landing page located in /var/www/html. a second directory located in /var/www/agv-guru and a third directory located in /var/www/owncloud/.

I have an alias set up for both owncloud and the agv-guru folder and everything was working properly for months.

For whatever reason I decided that instead of having a separate server (raspberry-pi) running pi-hole, I would go ahead and install it on my existing server. I quickly realized that my website was down and I un-installed Pi-Hole, which may or may not have made matters worse.

I'm looking for help troubleshooting this one as I am not entirely sure whats going on.

Here is what i know so far.

- The folders are still located in the same directory just like before.
- The folders are owned by www-data.
- The Document Root is /var/www/html.
- The Alias is still set up for both agv-guru and owncloud.
     /var/www/html/index.html still runs as normal with the exception of one photo not loading that was being pulled from the agv-guru folder.
- Webserver is Apache2

**Edit 1.**

I just cleared the logs hoping to just reload the service but I get an error.

`usr@Server:/var/log/apache2# service apache2 reload`

`apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.`

So I ran the status as shown below.

`usr@Server:/var/log/apache2# service apache2 status`

```
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
       └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: inactive (dead) since Tue 2017-10-17 22:16:29 CDT; 58s ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 14594 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Process: 14577 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14577]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14577]: no listening sockets available, shutting down    
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14577]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14577]: Action 'start' failed.
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14577]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14577]:  *
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14594]:  * Stopping Apache httpd web server apache2
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server apache2[14594]:  *
Oct 17 22:16:29 Server systemd[1]: Started LSB: Apache2 web server.
Oct 17 22:16:36 Server systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

**Edit 2**

`sudo  netstat -natp | grep ':80.*LISTEN'`

Yields

`tcp     0      0 0.0.0.0:80     0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN
1636/lighttpd`

**Solution**

With sborsky's help the solution was found.

When installing pi-hole lighttpd was also installed. This webserver was occupying the port preventing apache from running.

Comment: could you post the access_log and error_log entries related to the request resulting in 404?

Comment: Please see the first edit to my question

Comment: find out which process is hogging port 80: `netstat -natp | grep ':80.*LISTEN'` (run this as root or using sudo)

Comment: Please see Edit 2

Comment: Edit 2 contains your answer: lighttpd (a differrent HTTP server, not Apache) is running and probably is where your 404 errors came from.
Stop and disable lighttpd, then (re)start Apache. Try your webbrowser again.

Comment: Awesome, I guess lighttpd was installed with pi-hole but not uninstalled. Thanks for the help